# Fruit Fly Hybrids

Tags: genetics, reproductive-biology, species-distribution

I have a food waste bin in which I put fruit scraps. The fruits come from all over the world, mainly Europe though.

I'm in the UK.

I assume the fruit Fly eggs are already in the fruit, in which case they originate in the same country as the fruit.

Are they all the same species? Am I creating Hybrids in my waste bin?

Comment: @Remi.b your second statement is incorrect. While D.melanogaster is a genetic model organism, it is only one of hundreds of species in the genus [Drosophila]( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drosophila). Also your first statement is incomplete. It is the ability to produce fertile offspring that usually classified a species, as hybrids such as ligers or mules are, for the most part, sterile, though there is active controversy to the validity of the reproductive argument for speciation as well,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably they are not all the same species, as there are many fruit fly species in the UK and all over the world. It is also probable that you are **not** creating hybrids, as fruit flies have quite specific mating behaviours that change rapidly sometimes even between strains.

Anyway, you are assuming that the eggs come with the fruit, but that's hardly believable unless you already see larvae when you ate the fruit. *Drosophila melanogaster* has one of the fastest developments (22h since egg fertilisation, although it can vary with temperature). So, if we take for granted a week span since they were taken out of the country until you bought them (which is very optimistic) you would already see larvae in the fruit. In short, the flies that are thriving in your fruit bin are common flies from the UK.

In case you want to know, the most common flies in the UK according to [this article](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/271781730_The_Distribution_and_Abundance_of_Woodland_Species_of_British_Drosophila_(Diptera_Drosophilidae)) is *Drosophila subobscura* and *obscura*, which are pretty similar in development to *D. melanogaster*.

Comment: Excellent thanks very much for your reply. Im amazed that the fruit flies are local species - there are so many in such a short time whenever fruit is left lying around. I guess you've answered that too!